# No mail with empy subject in MDaemon

Tags: mdaemon

The people of IS ask me to block mails without subject(empty subjects), i'm using `MDaemon 9.5.1`, one of them gave me this rules

```
[Rule015]
RuleName=no empy subject
Enable=No
ThisRuleCondition=All
ProcessQueue=LOCAL
Condition01=SUBJECT|reg exp|AND|^..+$|
Action01=skip rule|"1"
[Rule016]
RuleName=empty subject
Enable=No
ThisRuleCondition=All
ProcessQueue=BOTH
Condition01=SUBJECT|exists|AND|
Action01=send note|"to <$SENDER$>","from <MDaemon@mydomain.com>","subject <Mail Rejected.>","x-flag=attach <$COPYOFMESSAGE$, MIME> -X","","Bla bla bla"
Action02=send note|"to <oneofthem@mydomain.com>","from <MDaemon@mydomain.com>","subject <Mail rejected notification.>","x-flag=attach <$COPYOFMESSAGE$, MIME> -X","","from:$SENDER$  ","to:$RECIPIENT$  ","subject: $SUBJECT$  ","date: $DATESTAMP$  ","time: $CURRENTTIME$"
Action03=delete|
```

I copied this form `cfrules.dat` file located in the app folder of the MDaemon installation directory, so, they say this is the correct setup, but, this rules doesn't really work as it should, it block mails with no subject and some that does have a subject, workers are now complaining a lot, and i want to be OK with both, the security and workers.

so, need a help here, i'm just trying to block mails with empty subjects, but it also can be by length, till now i have no success

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change

```
[Rule016]
......
ProcessQueue=BOTH  
......
```

to

```
[Rule016]
......
ProcessQueue=LOCAL  
......
```

and now it is working, hope it can help someone else